# how to extend entity framework ,To achieve this effect

Tags: entity-framework

how to extend entity framework ,To achieve this effect

db.Users.Delete(o=>o.sex=="girl")
db.Users.Update(o=>o.sex="girl")

Can batch modification and deletion, insert data

---

### 怎样扩展entity framework ，可以实现批量修改、删除和插入数据

Answer (score 0):

In Entity Framework 4 that's part of .NET 4.0 there is a method on the ObjectContext

ExecuteStoredCommand(string cmdText,  object[] parameters)

This allows to execute set based operations directly against your datastore.

In your example you could do something like:

```
db.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM [User] WHERE Sex = '{0}'", new[] {"girl"});
```